# How to compare the total number of records against the total number of records that matches a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: `Order_Header` and `Order_Detail`. All `Order_Detail` rows contain a reference to an `Order_Header_ID`. I need to return data where (the count of `Order_Details` for that `Order_Header` has `Product_ID = 185 AND Status = 'Completed'`), matches the (total count of that product contained within the `Order_Details` for that `Order_Header_ID`).

For example, Order_Header_ID number 200 has 2 Records in the Order_Detail's table. Both Records are product_ID 185. I need to check that both of those records have the Status 'Completed', and if so, return the Order_Header_ID. So I'm basically comparing the total number of product 185 on the order, against the total number of product 185 with the status complete.

Here's what I have so far in SQL Server, however I feel like I'm not approaching this right.

```
SELECT 
    Order_Header.Order_Header_ID 
FROM 
    Order_Header
INNER JOIN 
    Order_Detail ON Order_Header.Order_Header_ID = Order_Detail.Order_Header_ID
WHERE
    Product_ID = 185
    AND Order_Detail.Status = 'Completed'
    AND (SELECT COUNT(Order_Header_ID)
         FROM Order_Detail 
         WHERE Product_ID = 185) = COUNT(Order_Header.Order_Header_ID)
```

Any help is appreciated. Below is the database structure. Substitute Product ID 185 for Product ID 1 in this instance.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Header]
(
    [Order_Header_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Client_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Consultant_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Commision_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Date_Ordered] [datetime] NULL,
    [Order_Received] [datetime] NULL,
    [Payment_Received] [datetime] NULL,
    [Order_Summary_Sent] [datetime] NULL,
    [Countdown_Complete] [datetime] NULL

    CONSTRAINT [Order_Header$PrimaryKey]  
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Order_Header_ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Detail]
(
    [Order_Detail_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Order_Header_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Product_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Line_Number] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [money] NULL,
    [VAT] [money] NULL,
    [Total_Price] [money] NULL,
    [Commision] [money] NULL,
    [Final] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](255) NULL

    CONSTRAINT [Order_Detail$PrimaryKey] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Order_Detail_ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]
(
    [Product_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Product_Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product_Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Standard_Charge] [money] NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL

    CONSTRAINT [Products$PrimaryKey] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Product_ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO Products (Product_Name) VALUES ('Money Laundering / ID')

INSERT INTO Order_Header (Client_ID) VALUES (1001)
INSERT INTO Order_Header (Client_ID) VALUES (2002)

INSERT INTO Order_Detail (Order_Header_ID, Product_ID, [Status]) VALUES (1, 1, 'Completed')
INSERT INTO Order_Detail (Order_Header_ID, Product_ID, [Status]) VALUES (1, 1, '')
INSERT INTO Order_Detail (Order_Header_ID, Product_ID, [Status]) VALUES (2, 1, 'Completed')
INSERT INTO Order_Detail (Order_Header_ID, Product_ID, [Status]) VALUES (2, 1, 'Completed')
GO
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your tables with sample data and desired results, as text in your question, ideally with create and insert scripts.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!

Comment: I've added the script and sample data into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to return data where (the count of Order_Details for that Order_Header has Product_ID = 185 AND Status = 'Completed'), matches the (total count of that product contained within the Order_Details for that Order_Header_ID)

If I understand correctly, you want the order header ids where all the statuses for product 185 are completed.

If so, you don't need a `join`.  Assuming you only want orders that have at least 1 such product:

```
select od.order_header_id
from order_details od
where od.product_id = 185
group by od.order_header_id
having sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 0 else 1 end) = 0;
```

An alternative method uses `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from order_headers oh
where not exists (select 1
                  from order_details od
                  where od.order_header_id = o.order_header_id and
                        od.product_id = 185 and
                        (od.status <> 'Completed' or od.status is null)
                 );
```

With an index on `order_details(order_header_id, product_id status)`, this is likely to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I should clarify. 
I have Product ID 9 (Bank Account). I can only open this bank account, if all ID check products (185) have the Status 'Completed'. There can be multiple ID Check Products associated with 1 bank account. Therefore I need to compare the number of ID Check Products on an order, against the total number that have the Status Completed. If the numbers much, then we can open the account. I test your response and the ID still gets returned if at least 1 of them is completed, when I need to make sure that all of them have been completed.

Comment: @Alexh . .  Neither of these match if even one `order_detail` on the account has product `185` with a status other than `'Completed'`.  Can you put some data in a db/sql fiddle of some sort?

Comment: I think you're right, my bad. The status of the product I was looking at was NULL, so it was still returning in the SQL statement. I've wrapped it in a ISNULL([Status],'') within the Having clause and it's no longer returning the Order_Header_ID that doesn't have the status complete. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexH . . . I modified the answer.  I don't expect a column named `status` to be `NULL`, because there should always be a `status`.  But that is an assumption on my part, and not true of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are after is a conditional aggregate in the `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT OH.Order_Header_ID
FROM dbo.Order_Header OH
     JOIN dbo.OrderDetail OD ON OH.Order_Header_ID = OD.Order_Header_ID
WHERE OH.ProductID = 186 --Assumed on the table, as not qualified in the question
GROUP BY OH.Order_Header_ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE OD.Status = 'Completed' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the Order_Header_ID, you do not need to include the Order_Detail in the FROM since that will return one result for each line in Order_Detail, you can do a Select like this that will check that the current Order_ID has Completed lines and does not have any not completed lines:

```
SELECT 
    Order_Header.Order_Header_ID 
FROM 
    Order_Header
WHERE Product_ID = 185
    AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Order_Detail 
            WHERE Order_Header.Order_Header_ID = Order_Detail.Order_Header_ID  AND Order_Detail.Status = 'Completed')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Order_Detail 
            WHERE Order_Header.Order_Header_ID = Order_Detail.Order_Header_ID  AND Order_Detail.Status <> 'Completed')
```